# How to pop a message and don't disturb the following process in python？

Tags: python, messagebox

How to pop a message and don't disturb the following process in python, in case of the user needn't to click the accept button on the message box.

I use `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('xyz Demo','happy new year')`, but there is a accept button on the message box. I just want the message to be a information, and the following code don't be stopped by the message pop.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: you will need to make a frame of your own and open it non-modal ... I think at least ... showinfo will block until it quits

Comment: Yes, now it is block until I click accept button.